# How to develop a reponsive layout using liferay 6.2 ?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, liferay-6

I developed a 3 column layout which looks fine in desktop version. but in tablet and in mobile, 3-column layout looks like a single column layout, where the portlets are stacking up.

As i am new to bootstrap 2.3.2 and liferay 6.2 version, i am not sure how to do.

Below is the same layout code which i wrote :

```
<div class="Sample" id="main-content" class="container-fluid" role="main">
<div class="portlet-layout row-fluid">
    <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-first span1" id="column-1">
        $processor.processColumn("column-1", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-first")
    </div>
    <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-last span9" id="column-2">
        $processor.processColumn("column-2", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-last")
    </div>
    <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-last span2" id="column-3">
        $processor.processColumn("column-3", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-last")
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Responsive design most of the time means 'adapt the design to the device'.
Bootstrap interprets this as 'stack elements instead of displaying them side by side' for smaller screens.

If that is not what you want, use fixed widths instead.